# When I connect to firebase, I only see the structures and no devices (Nest API)

Tags: firebase, q, nest-api

I am trying to read basic information about thermostats using the methods in the thermostat control example (https://developer.nest.com/documentation/control), but when I connect to firebase I only see the `structure` object (which only contains `name`, `away`, `smoke_co_alarms`, `structure_id` and `thermostats`) in the snapshot– There is no `devices` object. I am connecting to firebase using

```
    var nestToken = $.cookie('nest_token');
    var dataRef = new Firebase('wss://developer-api.nest.com/');
    dataRef.auth(nestToken);
```

I tried to connect directly to devices using `wss://developer-api.nest.com/devices`, but that only returns an `undefined` data-structure.

I've also tried connecting to firebase using `https://developer-api.nest.com/` and `https://developer-api.nest.com/`, but they raised an authorization error and caused my javascript to go into an infinite loop sending requests.

I'm reading data using:

```
dataRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();
    structure = firstChild(data.structures);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.structures);
    console.log(data.devices);
    console.log(data.devices.thermostats);
    console.log(structure.thermostats);
};
```

Lastly, I tried it on an account with real devices and one with virtual devices, so I know that couldn't be causing it (even though I didn't expect it to).

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? The issue couldn't be in my App.js file, could it? Is there some configuration I need to do on the user's end in addition to the authentication? I get the feeling it's probably something really simple that's staring me in the face.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured it out: It's a permissions issue. When my client-profile was setup, it only requested permission to read the away/home status. So when I query Firebase it only returns the a snapshot with `structure` because that is where the away/home status can be read. So, in summary, if you're not seeing the `devices` structure, even though devices are associated with the user, **check your client permissions**.

Comment: Seem to remember someone else got caught with that on a related question. This hasn't been a problem for me because I set-up with full permissions, but it's worth knowing. It's also the sort of thing which you'd hope Nest were watching for here, and stepping in with a quick answer (particularly since StackOverflow is the only option for support with this API).

Answer (score 1):

Using (some of) your code, I have no trouble seeing the devices object:

```
var dataRef = new Firebase('wss://developer-api.nest.com');
dataRef.auth(nestTokenLive);
dataRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.devices);
});
```

Results in:

```
> Object {devices: Object, structures: Object}
> Object {thermostats: Object}
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that code isn't buggy.  What version of firebase are you using? The example used 1.0.15, but I know the current release is 1.0.17.

Comment: Scratch that. I just updated my version of firebase and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Bit late, but in answer to your question, I'm on 1.0.17 - I only came across Firebase because of the Nest API and initially viewed it as an unnecessary extra framework, and one more thing to have to learn. But the REST streaming is fantastic and I am now considering pushing all my home monitoring stats up to Firebase, just so that I can stream back to my own clients.